# Scala 3. Adapting Continuation monad example from Haskell to Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, types, monads, continuations

Learning Scala 3 with monadic topics.

came across understandable breakdown of Continuation monad at https://jsdw.me/posts/haskell-cont-monad/

When I try to adopt simple code into Scala

```hs
twoC = \out -> out 2
helloC = \out -> out "hello"
ret val = \out -> out val

inC `bind` fn = \out -> inC (\inCval -> (fn inCval) out)

fourC = twoC `bind` \two -> ret (two*2)

twoHelloC = twoC `bind` \two ->
              helloC `bind` \hello ->
                ret $ (show two)++hello
```

i can have `fourC(identity)` compiling and working well.
But `bind`s in `twoHelloC` complain about Int/String type mismatch.

current impl of bind I have:

```scala
val twoCont: (Int => Int) => Int =
  out => out(2)

val helloCont: (String => String) => String =
  out => out("hello")

type Cont[X, R] = (X => R) => R

extension[A, FinalRes] (inCont: Cont[A, FinalRes]) {
  infix def bind[B](fn: A => Cont[B, FinalRes]): Cont[B, FinalRes] = {
    (out: B => FinalRes) => inCont(inContVal => (fn(inContVal))(out))
  }
}

val twoHelloCont: (String => String) => String =
  twoCont bind (two =>
    helloCont bind (hello =>  // here it is unhappy to see Cont[String, String]
      return_(two.toString + hello)
      )
    )
```

**Question**:
how would you implement infix `bind` in Scala, and why Haskell typesystem permits `twoHelloC` to compile? What do i miss here?

thanks

Comment: Where is your Scala code translating this Hashell code and failing with this compile error?

Comment: Without your code, questions "translate from language X into language Y" are offtopic  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/how-should-we-tag-code-translation-questions

Comment: @DmytroMitin - even if we look just at haskell code - i can't get a clue why his code type checks for him while working with both strings and ints

Comment: you've not included your implementations of `twoCont` or `helloCont` in scala? could you add that?

Comment: @Joe, added. let's see Dmytro's answer

Comment: @Joe, take a look that precisely those definitions, being too rigid in types, brought me to error there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have questions what types were inferred in Haskell you can always ask `:t ...` in ghci

```hs
ghci> :t twoHelloC
twoHelloC :: ([Char] -> t) -> t
ghci> :t fourC
fourC :: (Integer -> t) -> t
ghci> :t bind
bind :: ((t1 -> t2) -> t3) -> (t1 -> t4 -> t2) -> t4 -> t3
ghci> :t ret
ret :: t1 -> (t1 -> t2) -> t2
ghci> :t helloC
helloC :: (String -> t) -> t
ghci> :t twoC
twoC :: (Integer -> t) -> t
```

In Scala you should start with ordinary methods. Verbose translation is

```scala
def twoC[A](out: Int => A): A = out(2)
def helloC[A](out: String => A): A = out("hello")
def ret[A1, A2](`val`: A1): (A1 => A2) => A2 =
  (out: A1 => A2) => out(`val`)
def bind[A1, A2, A3, A4](inC: (A1 => A2) => A3)(fn: A1 => A4 => A2): A4 => A3 =
  (out: A4) => inC((inCval: A1) => fn(inCval)(out))
def fourC[A]: (Int => A) => A =
  bind[Int, A, A, Int => A](twoC[A])((two: Int) => ret[Int, A](two * 2))
def twoHelloC[A]: (String => A) => A =
  bind[Int, A, A, String => A](twoC[A])((two: Int) =>
    bind[String, A, A, String => A](helloC[A])((hello: String) =>
      ret[String, A](two.toString + hello)
    )
  )
```

which can be shortened to

```scala
def twoC[A](out: Int => A): A = out(2)
def helloC[A](out: String => A): A = out("hello")
def ret[A1, A2](`val`: A1): (A1 => A2) => A2 = out => out(`val`)
def bind[A1, A2, A3, A4](inC: (A1 => A2) => A3)(fn: A1 => A4 => A2): A4 => A3 =
  out => inC(inCval => fn(inCval)(out))
def fourC[A]: (Int => A) => A = bind(twoC[A])(two => ret(two * 2))
def twoHelloC[A]: (String => A) => A =
  bind(twoC[A])(two =>
    bind(helloC[A])(hello =>
      ret(two.toString + hello)
    )
  )
```

Now you can add `extension`, `infix`, `Cont` etc.

Is is clear how to finish translation?

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. when i was playing, i also used `:t` to sniff types and actually started with this bigger signature with 4 types... still that brought me to the same type mismatch. let me see if i do smth bad when i define bind as `infix`...

Comment: ah, i see one interesting stuff in your variant, you define `def twoC[A](out: Int => A): A = out(2)` , not `def twoC(out: Int => Int): Int = out(2)`

Comment: and this is precisely where i didn't use `:t` to sniff the type, i thought that it was obvious: Int->Int->Int... ughhh... Dmytro, since you're powerful coder, can you explain me why they dont' use Int->Int->Int for twoC ? cant get a clue how A appears there

Comment: `out` fn is like a continuation, and `A` is a final type, a result type after continuation is applied - i thought it should be Int for `twoC`

Comment: Dmitro, thanks, that was precisely the error with A instead of Int/String, and when i keep my old impl `type Cont[X, R] = (X => R) => R

extension[A, FinalRes] (inCont: Cont[A, FinalRes]) {
  infix def bind[B](fn: A => Cont[B, FinalRes]): Cont[B, FinalRes] = {
    (out: B => FinalRes) => inCont(inContVal => (fn(inContVal))(out))
  }
}
` as is (i like it better for clarity it brings for me) and it still works

Comment: that `A` thingy is smth is counter-intuitive for me in this whole small piece of code... i just can't understand it :)

Comment: @Max *"can you explain me why they dont' use `Int->Int->Int` for `twoC`?"* Because there's no need. The signature is kept as generic as possible just so that the implementation (the body, the right hand side) satisfies the specification/contract (signature). And this becomes important later. `fourC` and `twoHelloC` use `twoC[A]` (`twoC @a` in Haskell syntax), not `twoC[Int]`.

Comment: @Max In `def twoC[X, Y](out: X): Y = out(2)` you can see that `out` is applied, so it should be `def twoC[A1, A2, Y](out: A1 => A2): Y`. You apply `out` to `2`, so `A1=Int`, you return the result of application, so `Y=A2`. So the signature is `def twoC[A](out: Int => A): A`. Actually, I've just described a part of [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#An_inference_algorithm) algorithm, the actual type inference algorithm used in Haskell. In Scala this is more tricky because of subtyping and local type inference.

Comment: that last comment about _Hindley-Milner algorithm_ is very interesting. never heard of it... i see how many topics open up... it looks like their thought process goes from the result as the starting point back to the `twoC`...

Comment: _In Scala this is more tricky because of subtyping and local type inference._ what is local type inference, and how haskell is different in that regard? every answer from you all these 2 weeks you help me seem to open up a new can of worms :) ...

Comment: @Max https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/214757 In Haskell in principle if you modify your code in one place it can stop to compile far from it. Scala tries to make compile errors close to modification place.

Comment: @Max Subtyping makes inference harder because the compiler must solve system of inequlities rather than system of equations. There is algebraic subtyping https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/stephen-dolan/thesis.pdf but Scala doesn't use it.

Comment: @Max Scala 3 uses DOT calculus https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3428276

Comment: ok, cheers for such detailed answers you always give. i think you gave me the mental model: they start with maximum flexible signature as a starting point: `def twoC[A1, A2, Y](out: A1 => A2): Y`

Comment: @Max Yeah, even `def twoC[X, Y](out: X): Y`